# AWS Resources of an account invited to an Organization

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-amplify, aws-organizations

I have looked for days to find the answer to this question in the official docs but couldn't find anything specific (could it be because there are so many of them!)

1. What happens to resources of an account when the aforementioned
   account gets invited to an Organization?
2. And in case, the resource
   are moved with the account (what I would expect), are those resource
   manageable from the Organization as any other created directly by
   the Organization account?

Sorry for any confusion in the questions, I am still new to this Organization stuff.

**Background**:
As many out there, I have started with a personal account which runs Amplify, Elastic Bean Stalk and a couple other services. Now I would like to create an Organization and invite this account into it, but I can't understand what would happen to the services attached to the account.

I know that I could try and see what happens, but I would prefer to have the smoothest transition possible since the Organization account would actually be used by other people as well.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Basically nothing happens. Resource cannot be moved. And *"are those resource manageable from the Organization as any other created directly by the Organization account"* is not true for *any* resources unless you clarify exactly what "manageable" means in your context.

Comment: I am still new to Org and thought that you could do some basic management of the resource as if you were the root of the account that have the resources. But from you comment, it doesn't seem so. Thanks!